# Has the DC character The Question ever used a gun or carried a gun with him?

Tags: dc

I'm asking about the original Vic Sage version of The Question, and not the new 52 Renee Montoya version.

I do know that he has killed in the past, but has he ever used a gun for one of these kills, or has him at least ever strapped a gun on him before going out to investigate?

Comment: Does *Justice League Unlimited* count? That's Vic, but a different continuity.

Comment: I may be thinking of *JLU*'s Crimson Avenger or Vigilante instead of The Question. They all wear hats.

Comment: This is really hard to answer as a negative unless you've read every single Question story.